# How to find out if i get a 404 response from the src attribute of an img?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, jsonp

I am building an AngularJS web app and at the moment I am creating a form to allow the user to link to youtube videos. I have a thumbnail associated with youtube videos and when the user enters a youtube link, i fetch the image from `https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/maxresdefault.jpg`

That goes into this:

```
<img src="{{element.video.thumb}}>
```

So, my current solution is:

```
element.video.thumb = `https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/maxresdefault.jpg`
```

My problem is that not all youtube videos have their thumbnail available at that link. I want to be able to identify if a video has it available or not. I notice that I get a 404 response in my console when a thumbnail is not available. So I tried to check if the thumbnail exists using $http service. I tried both variants below:

```
$http.get(`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/maxresdefault.jpg`)
$http.jsonp(`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/maxresdefault.jpg`,{jsonpCallbackparam: "callback"})
```

The first one gives me a CORS error, and the second one doesn't work because the MIME type of the response is `image/jpeg` and it gives error when trying to execute the callback.

#### My first question is:

Why assigning the link to the src attribute of an img fetches the resource with no issues, but trying to access the resource with ah HTTP request gives a CORS error?

#### My second question is:

How can I execute some code if I get a 404 response after assigning the img src attribute?

Comment: Your getting a CORS error, because CORS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

About your second Question (and the title of this Question) the solution should be to use the [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent) Event.
Use `.addEventListener()` to add the required EventListener.

Comment: The event is [*`Error`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent) not *`onerror`*. *onerror* is the name of the HTML attribute that configures the handler. But, **[inline HTML event handlers should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** - - `.addEventListener()` is the modern standard. Also, W3 Schools is widely known to have incomplete, out of date or flat out wrong information. Use the Mozilla Developer's Network instead.

Comment: Thanks for this it's very useful!

Answer (score 0):

An XMLHttpRequest is being used in the .get to set the image from the browser, so a CORS error is triggered.

In your request you need to ask the target server for permission, using a crossOrigin attribute.

You can see: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/